# Change a section of a line when it matches the first half with space between the two substrings (Regex)

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to change all the grades of one student using a regex check in Perl.
The file (grades.txt) is formatted as follows:

```
Student One - Individual Project - MF
Student Two - OOP2 - B
Student One - Other Module - C
Student Two - Other Module - F
Student One - Final Module - A+
```

What I have so far is `cat grades.txt | perl -ne 's/(w{1,2})\+?(?!.)/A/g; print;`
This changes all the grades to As, but I just want Student One's grades changed to As.
I have also tried changing the regex to `(<?="Student One")\K(w{1,2})\+?(?!.)` but then that doesn't match anything and I have a feeling it is to do with the fact that there are additional characters between "Student One" and the grade.

I'd also like to output the new, changed results to a new file (for example Agrades.txt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to avoid `cat` when you want to pass the contents of a file to a Perl program. If you specify a list of files as parameters, then Perl will read through them all.

This solution uses perl's `-p` switch, which executes the content of `-e` for each line in the input file before printing it out. I have also used the `/x` regex modifier which allows you to add insignificant whitespace so that the pattern can be laid out more clearly.

The substitution is very similar to your own, but is followed by an `if` statement modifier which ensures that the changes will happen only on lines that start with `Student One`. The `\b` matches a *word boundary* and it is to ensure that the student's name ends with `One` instead of something like `Student Onedin`.

```
perl -pe"s/ [A-Z]+ \+? $ /A/x if /^Student One\b/" grades.txt
```

You can open an output file inside the Perl program, but it is usually simpler to redirect the output using `>`, like this

```
perl -pe"s/ [A-Z]+ \+? $ /A/x if /^Student One\b/" grades.txt > Agrades.txt
```

that way you can check the result by sending it to your terminal, and then write it to a file when you are sure that it is correct.

Comment: @AutomatedRandomated: My original code allowed for whitespace after the grade and before the end of the line. I've removed that for simplicity (there's no need to add the newline back) but if you want to add that back then it would look like `s/ [A-Z]+ \+? (?= \s* $ ) /A/x`